# How do I model an EFT Surge wave equation on voltage source with LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to put the following equation onto my voltage source on LTSpice to get the same waveform. The waveforms and equations are attached
[image]

Comment: I am new to LTSpice, I cannot find out exactly how to put in the formula in voltage source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert an *arbitrary behavioral voltage source*, or `BV` component. Right-click it and set its `Value` parameter to `V=A*Vp*(1-exp(-time/tau1))*exp(-time/tau2)`. Insert a SPICE command somewhere in your schematic that reads `.param Vp=1, A=1.037, tau1=407.4n, tau2=68.22u`. Run a 100μs simulation. For the current, do similar but with an *arbitrary behavioral current source*, or `BI` component.

One thing to note: LTspice doesn't have a good idea where to set the time steps for transient simulations with behavioral sources, so you may need to customize the `Maximum Timestep` parameter in your transient simulation command by reducing it to an appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

Like your other question use the linear piecewise model. Use python or matlab to generate the points from the equation and export the x,y (time,magnitude) points into a CSV file. Import that file into LTSpice under voltage source then advanced and PWL FILE...

Comment: I was wondering if I could put the equation on the arbitrary voltage source?

Comment: It would be a good feature but personally I don't know if this is possible.